# The type initializer for 'DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net, report

I'm developing a website in which I need to show docked reports

With .Net framework 3.5 its working fine but when upgraded to framework 4.0 I'm getting the following error in the code.

```
The type initializer for 'DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport' threw an exception.
```

and in the browser, I'm getting an error as

```
This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding following element in web.config file under system.web tag

```
<trust legacyCasModel="true"/>
```

reference link

http://blogs.rev-net.com/ddewinter/2010/03/02/tip-20-opting-out-of-security-changes-in-net-4-in-asp-net-and-custom-appdomains/